# how to pass id from jquery to any div class?

Tags: html

I am getting id in jquery from heading class and showing a alert message
but i dont want a alert message i want to send that id in a div

```
<div class="bar">
        <span class="heading" id="1">
            Men<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="heading" id="2">
            Women<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="heading" id="3">
            Kids<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>

<div class="site-nav" role="navigation">
</div>
```

I want to get that id in class "site-nav" i mean to say when click on men get 1 for women get 2 for kids get 3

from juery i am fetching that id but not able to get on div having class site-nav

```
 $('.heading').click(function() { 
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(id);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".heading").on("click",function() {
    $(".site-nav").html(`${this.id}: ${this.innerHTML}`);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
  <span class="heading" id="1">Men<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <span class="heading" id="2">Women<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <span class="heading" id="3">Kids<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="site-nav" role="navigation">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text text from jquery to achieve passing the id value to the site-nav.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.bar span').on('click', (e) => {
    $('.site-nav').text(e.target.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
  <span class="heading" id="1">
            Men<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
  <span class="heading" id="2">
            Women<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
  <span class="heading" id="3">
            Kids<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>

<div class="site-nav" role="navigation">
</div>
```

If you are looking for pure JS solution then you can try the following code too

```js
(function(document) {
  var clickHandler = function(e) {
    var siteNav = document.querySelector('.site-nav');
    siteNav.textContent = e.target.id;
  };
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.bar span');
  elements.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler));
})(document);
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <span class="heading" id="1">
            Men<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
  <span class="heading" id="2">
            Women<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
  <span class="heading" id="3">
            Kids<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
</div>

<div class="site-nav" role="navigation">
</div>
```

Comment: i am getting 1,2 and 3 how can i set this 1,2,3 to this class="site-nav"  ?

Comment: <nav class="site-nav" role="navigation">
            

                <?php
                    $cloth=new ClothType();
                    
                    $getCloth=$cloth->getAllClothTypeById(1);             i have above code in the file and want to get that 1,2,3 on this method getAllClothTypeById(1);

Comment: Do you want the `nav` class when the user clicks on the first id to be `site-nav 1` like this? or do you need the text content inside the element with class `site-nav` to be the id of the menu clicked?

Comment: This combination of PHP and javaScript won't work. PHP essentially gets compiled at the server-side and the JavaScript at the client side. In case for this to work when the user clicks, you would need to fetch the data from server via an endpoint or an API